# How do I post a non-string value in a Scala Http request?

Tags: scala.js

From a Scala program, I need to send values with different primitive types to a Node server.

```
Http("http://middleware-api:3000/createPromoCodeInCms?")
    .postForm
    .param("lifetime", 5)
    .method("POST")
    .asString
```

This does not compile:

```
[error] /Users/corbac/Desktop/spark-projects/App.scala:192:24: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(5)
[error]  required: String
[error]                 .param("lifetime", 5)
[error]                                    ^
```

However it seems like only strings are accepted as body parameters. Is it possible to post non-string types such as a number or a boolean? If yes how do I do it?

I am using Scala 2.11.

Comment: Would `5.toString()` work for you?

Comment: @sjrd it would work, but it would be a string, and I need it to be a number

Comment: You're sending an HTTP request. At the end of the day, params in HTTP requests are *always* strings. HTTP is a string-based protocol.

Comment: @sjrd ok but then how do I tell the server which will receive the request that ultimately 5 is a number and not a string?

Comment: The server needs to know that it expects an int for that param, in order to parse the string that it receives as an int. The way to do this depends on your server component that handles http requests.